# Disabling logging frameworks on external libraries

Tags: java, log4j

I have an external library that uses log4j, at first the logging on console was useful but now its trying to print KB xml messages on the console and its just not usable anymore.

I tried some of the programmatical solutions posted on this site but to no avail, i never used log4j and i find it frustrating that i need to learn it just to disable it because it is imposed by a library.

I tried

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext();
        Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
        Collection<LoggerConfig> loggers = config.getLoggers().values();
        for(LoggerConfig cfg: loggers) {
          cfg.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        }
```

And

```
List<Logger> loggers = Collections.<Logger>list(LogManager.getCurrentLoggers());
loggers.add(LogManager.getRootLogger());
for ( Logger logger : loggers ) {
    logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
}
```

But they dont complile

How is log4j disabled?

Comment: "I find it frustrating that I need to learn it just to disable it". You don't need to learn the library, just enough of the configuration to understand how logging levels and logging sources work. If you're already familiar with some logging library, this shouldn't be hard. If you're not familiar with *any* logging library, then you should learn one (I'd recommend SLF4J with Logback).

Comment: You surely have a good point. And i did try to learn the very basics but be as it may maybe i lack concentration or time but i cant get the logger to stop, and all the while im totally stuck. being in this situation i strongly feel that it really is a major issue for me and maybe others.

Comment: Well, the reason the code given in your example won't compile is because you're not using Log4J so it's not in your classpath. You might be able to put a config file in your classpath that overrides the one used by the library and disables all logging.

Comment: im using  log4j-core-2.1.jar and apache-logging-log4j.jar to run the first example.

Comment: So does it compile or not? You're giving out misleading information, which is not a good idea when you're trying to get help.

Comment: Sorry, i get "The method getContext() is undefined for the type LogManager" on the first line and "The type org.apache.logging.log4j.Level cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" and the second example runs but its ineffective, im running the code at the end of my main after launching the GUI.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `log4j-api` library at least (that's where `org.apache.logging.log4j.Level` seems to be situated).

Comment: i upgraded to apache-logging-log4j.jar
log4j-1.2-api-2.8.1.jar
log4j-core-2.8.1.jare but i get the same errors,

Answer (score 0):

After a long while i realized that SLF4J was also used by another library which ended up logging my messages.

In the end the following can be considered a remedy or at least a temporary solution against most unwanted logs

```
List<Logger> loggers = Collections.<Logger>list(LogManager.getCurrentLoggers());
loggers.add(LogManager.getRootLogger());
for ( Logger logger : loggers ) {
    logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
}
```

for log4j (with care of importing org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager and not java.util.logging.LogManager)

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger rootLogger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        rootLogger.setLevel(Level.toLevel("off"));
```

for SLF4J

As why the first

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext();
        Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
        Collection<LoggerConfig> loggers = config.getLoggers().values();
        for(LoggerConfig cfg: loggers) {
          cfg.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        }
```

couldnt compile i didnt figure out in the end